# Why can I print this list of lists, but only append all up to and not including the last element of each iteration?

Tags: python, loops, append

I can print the following list of lists fine, but when I append to an empty list, it skips the last on each iteration or gives me an index out of range error when I add one more.

This works:

```
ordered_results = []
temp = []
A = len(results[1])-2
i = 1
while i < len(results):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    while x < A:
        temp = [results[i][0], results[0][x], results[i][y]]
        print(temp)
        x+=1
        y+=1
    temp = [results[i][0], results[0][x], results[i][y]]
    print(temp)
    i+=1
ordered_results
```

Note: len(results[0]) = 240 and len(results[1] = 241

If you replace "print" with ordered_results.append(temp) it skips:

```
results[i][0], results[0][239], results[i][240]
```

each iteration.

(Note the code was expanded as I am messing around trying to figure this out, it was more compact before).

Comment: you could use a `for result in results` instead of the while loop, and drop the indexes. Would make your code much clearer (unrelated to your issue, but still...)

Comment: can you provide example input and expected output so as to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem? This looks rather complicated and hard to understand.

Comment: When the `while` loop ends, `x = 239` and `y = 240`. So you'll get an index error whenever `len(results[i]) < 241`.